# multiple questions in one question

Tags: discussion

Is this question should be asked in two different posts?

[Link](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/30495/5382)

IMO, I think this post is valid because here the OP is not able to remember his childhood serials. and hence he don't know which specific tag to use.

Also it would be funny to post two questions with same question title like:

- Can't remember the name of a TV show
- Can't remember the name of a TV show

I agree with OP to go with one post here. please clarify.

Comment: Multiple question in same question only bring multiple partial answeres.

Comment: Also, who's forcing the OP to use an identical title for both questions? They can write whatever they want in them, and it's actually *preferable* that the titles won't be this generic but rather briefly describe each show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each question should have its own subject line.  Most questions (but not all) contain a little bit about the movie (i.e. "Can't remember the name of this TV show with a large dragon from outer space in it", and "Can't remember the name of this TV show about a family lost in time with some lizard-looking creatures").

The question you linked could have definitely been split in two with much more information known to the reader before they even opened the question.